# What is the best known FPT result for 3-hitting set?

Tags: graph-algorithms, fixed-parameter-tractable

My research problem involves solving a special instance of the 3-Hitting Set problem, and I was wondering whether my result is actually significant (i.e. if it is better than the best known result for 3-Hitting Set).

I'm specifically interested in the case where the parameter is the optimal hitting set size.

I know the paper by [Niedermeier and Rossmanith](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570866703000091) that presents an algorithm of run-time $O(2.27^k + n)$, but that paper is pretty old.

Comment: If you look at [the papers that cite that paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=9325524540154631169&as_sdt=5,37&sciodt=0,37&hl=en), you'll find better results, e.g., by [Fernau](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=4059058900921347450&hl=en&as_sdt=5,37&sciodt=0,37). You should probably keep looking

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the [Parameterized Complexity](http://fpt.wikidot.com/fpt-races) Wiki, the currently best known FPT algorithm for 3-Hitting-Set has a complexity of $2.076^k \cdot n^{O(1)}$, the algorithm is from the [PhD thesis](http://liu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:23420/FULLTEXT01.pdf) of Magnus Wahlström.